# How can I exclude certain terms from Xcode's code completion? (auto complete, content assist)

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, indexing, code-completion

As we all know Xcode's code completion is awesome and necessary at the same time. But sometimes it can be be quite annoying as well...

Is there any way that I can modify the list of possible completion results?

E.g. I'm using "CGSizeMake" all the time, but never want to use "CGSizeMakeWithDictionaryRepresentation" that is suggested in the first place. So I would like to exclude the later one. Another example is "Nil" vs. "nil".

Any information regarding how the code completions works would be appreciated.

Comment: which version of xcode?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so. The code completion is generated from indexing the code within the project so anything that is included in the project will be available. Anything that you do to limit the indexing will break the code completion for changes to the code in the project.

Possible options for you include code snippets and, possibly but likely a lot of work, creating an Xcode plugin to try to modify the completion ([random sample plugin project](https://github.com/ksuther/KSImageNamed-Xcode)).

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly off topic, but you could try using AppCode. AppCode has a much more intelligent auto complete. With AppCode you can also create certain keywords for auto complete as well.