# Is it possible to exclude items from Xcode's code completion?

Tags: swift, xcode, code-completion

One of the worst offenders is `NSAccessibilityProtocol`, for example.

- The protocol declares lots of members (26 functions)
- Its conformed to by some of the most common object types (e.g. `NSView`, `NSWindow`) conform to it.

  - `NSObject` even has these methods! (Even though it doesn't conform to `NSAccessibilityProtocol` explicitly, for some reason)
- The function names contain common words like "frame", "style", "range", "size", "button", "menu", etc., so they come up really frequently as false positives (because of to fuzzy searching)
- Most (all?) of the members are deprecated

[image]

Is it possible to filter out these members from code completion? When I do need them, I would rather just look them up in the API docs manually, if it meant that they wouldn't disturb me the other 95% of the time.

Here are some similar questions on the topic, none of which are up to date and high quality:

1. [How can I exclude certain terms from Xcode's code completion? (auto complete, content assist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20030388/3141234), suggest was to use AppCode, obviously not exactly applicable
2. [Is there a way to improve Xcode's code completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23417418/3141234), old (2014), suggestion is to use a plugin (Xcode discontinued its support for plugins)
3. [Is there a way to disable or modify Xcode's code completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2218713/3141234), applies to an old Xcode version. `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/TextMacros.xctxtmacro` doesn't exist on my machine (Xcode Version 12.4 (12D4e))

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no way to customize this.

Comment: @matt I figured, but I thought I'd ask just in case. Boy I miss the days of Alcatraz.